# CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

In my app I'm using custom library to load svg files and loading process is a bit expensive so I've trying to move it into another thread. And I get "CalledFromWrongThreadException". According with example here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads everything must be ok but I still getting an error. What I'm missing?

```
public class SinglePhraseFragment extends Fragment {

View rootView;
String imageFileName;
int in_favorites, id;
SpannableString phrase;

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_phrase_layout, container, false);


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //loading svg file and converting it into drawable
            SVG svg = null;
            try {
                final ImageView phraseImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phraseImage);
                svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), imageFileName); //loading svg file
                final Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable(); //creating drawable from svg
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                    phraseImage.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

                //trying to set drawable to ImageView and getting error
                phraseImage.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        phraseImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (IOException e) {}
            catch (SVGParseException e) {}
        }
    }).start();

    return rootView;
}
```

So I've edited the code:

```
public class SinglePhraseFragment extends Fragment {

View rootView;
String imageFileName;
int in_favorites, id;
SpannableString phrase;

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_phrase_layout, container, false);


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //loading svg file and converting it into drawable
            SVG svg = null;
            try {
                final ImageView phraseImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phraseImage);
                svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), imageFileName); //loading svg file
                final Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable(); //creating drawable from svg
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                    phraseImage.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

                //trying to set drawable to ImageView and getting error
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        phraseImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                    }
                });
            catch (IOException e) {Log.e("app", "IOException");}
            catch (SVGParseException e) {Log.e("app", "SVGParseException");}
        }
    }).start();

    return rootView;
}
```

And this is logCat output:

```
06-14 23:11:33.476: W/dalvikvm(8270): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40abb228)
06-14 23:11:33.486: E/AndroidRuntime(8270): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-39961
06-14 23:11:33.486: E/AndroidRuntime(8270): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
06-14 23:11:33.486: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
06-14 23:11:33.486: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:736)
06-14 23:11:33.486: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:785)
06-14 23:11:33.486: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4013)
06-14 23:11:33.486: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8614)
06-14 23:11:33.486: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at android.view.View.setLayerType(View.java:10128)
06-14 23:11:33.486: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at com.potatopit.pick_app.SinglePhraseFragment$2.run(SinglePhraseFragment.java:74)
06-14 23:11:33.486: E/AndroidRuntime(8270):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Comment: First, never put empty exception handler blocks in your code. Use `Log.e()` to write them to LogCat if nothing else. Then, please post a stack trace showing your error.

Comment: phraseImage.setImageDrawable(drawable); updating ui from thread. update ui on the ui thread

Comment: post your stack trace. try using runOnUiThread to set the drawable to image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the stack trace tells you, you are attempting to call `setLayerType()` on a background thread. Please do that on the main application thread, such as inside the `Runnable` you are using with `runOnUiThread()`.

BTW, you may wish to use an `AsyncTask`, for cleaner code, rather than your current `Thread`-and-`runOnUiThread()` implementation.

Comment: Yes. That was a deal. Feels myself stupid right now... Thanks a lot)

Comment: @kroart consider using asynctask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Comment: @Raghunandan yeah will look

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are updating ui from the background thread. You need to update ui on the main ui thread.

Use runOnUiThread

```
      getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
          public void run() 
          { 
              phraseImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);            
          }
     });
```

Comment: I've just tried this. Error still present. See my first post.

Comment: @kroart as suggest by commonsware move the setlayer part of the code inside runonuithread. but i would suggest using asynctask for this purpose. no confusion